# All forms of N for which only one non abelian group of order n exists.

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

I want to find all forms of n for which only one non abelian group exists of order n. We do not need to look beyond square powers of primes. I believe this can be classified.

Comment: There are cases of groups of order $pq$ where there is a unique nonabelian semidirect product (think about the two groups of order $6$).

Comment: I want to classify all

Comment: Note that there is a cyclic group of any order (which is abelian). We can prove the result that this the unique group of order $n$ iff $n$ and $\phi (n) $ are coprime, so your statement holds for all of these cases atleast.

Comment: So in this case we dont have a non abelian group .Actually this can be improved as dixon gave all orders for which only abelian groups exist of order n.

Comment: what you are saying was subsequently proved by gallian

Comment: Ronit:  I think it would be very helpful for you to add the context in which this question arose, for you; e.g. adding any preliminary work you've done, that leads you to ask your question.?  Such context helps answerers understand material you've already learned, or are aware of, to then better help answer what you are looking for.

Comment: I have proved forms of n for which only abelian groups exist. So I think becuase it doesnt go to cubes....only squares are needed atmost ....this can be done.I dont thik it has been yet....for eg 75 21 55....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p_1,p_2,...,p_k$ be the prime factors of $n$, with repetition, in ascending order. (So, for example, for $n=147$, they would be $3,7,7$.)

Call a pair $p_i,p_j$ with $i<j$ *significant* if either (i) $p_i|(p_j-1)$; or  (ii) $p_i|(p_j+1)$ and $p_{j+1}=p_j$.

Then there exist two nonisomorphic nonabelian groups of order $n$ if either some prime occurs three or more times, or there exists more than one siginificant pair $p_i,p_j$.

So, for example, this holds for $n=147$, because there are two critical pairs, $p_1,p_2$ and $p_1,p_3$ , but it doesn't hold for $n=75$, because there is only one significant pair, $p_1,p_2$.

Comment: I believe then there exists one non abelain group for squarefree order iff there is only one significant pair....

Comment: Yes, that's more or less equivalent to what I said.

Comment: Yes the square are causing more trouble but i think it can be done...

Comment: $n=pq^2$ where $p$ is not 2 and $p|q+1$ then there exists one non abelian group of order $n$...generalising 75.